# Steam WSUS type server

Tags: linux, windows, steam

I am planning on getting a new gaming rig, but with a small SSD drive. I have lots of games in my Steam Library, but I don't want to install a large hard drive just to fit them all on. I also have a server running Debian in my home. What I would like to know is if there is a way to have the Linux server download the games and content to it, then I tell Steam on my client machines to pull content from there before going out to the regular Steam servers, mostly for game installs and updates. It would be awesome if the server also updated all the games in the library (i.e. once a day or once a week), as transferring through the LAN is much quicker.

I am not looking to install the games to the server, then run it over the network. What I am trying to do is have all the content go to that one server, then as I pick games on my library to install on my computer, it pulls from my local server as opposed to the Steam server that takes forever to download. Is there any way to set this up?

Comment: Why not just install a 1TB HDD on the gaming rig, and install your steam library there? If you decide you want a game on the SSD, you can always copy it over and make a junction point from the original folder on the HDD to the new folder on the SSD.

Comment: @nhinkle Many reasons why not, but I'm wanting it on a server. I have multiple computers that have various Steam games on them, and I'd like one central server that keeps all the games up to date for all my platforms (I run a Mac as well)

Comment: I know there isn't anything like this built-in. You might be able to sniff the connection between the Steam client and Valve's servers using wireshark, and then try to set something up (maybe with iptables on your router?) to intercept that traffic and send it to your server.  Or perhaps run everything for steam's IP space through a really aggressive caching server?

Comment: Steam does not support this and never will

Comment: @ramhound If you find a source, post that as an answer

Comment: @Ramhound jsut because it's closed source doesn't mean it's not possible that its built in. WSUS is closed source and it does this.

Comment: @PsychoData WSUS is designed to do this I don't understand the comment.  Microsoft also supports doing it Valve does not.  My comment is valid Steam is DRM there is no reason Valve would support something like this it wouldn't sell many games and would reduce the level of security of Steam's DRM

Comment: How would it reduce the amount of security? who's to say they cant encrypt their lovely store of games/game updates? Just because it's closd source doesn't mean that they dont have it. Thats not to say they may not. Honestly, I dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ramhound mentions, this is not possible... giving up the search

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @jawa the answer is that it can't do it

Comment: This answer is valid.  This cannot be done with Valve support.

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround: I imagine you could set up a virtual Windows machine on your debian server that keeps all Steam games up to date and the install-folder is on a LAN-accessable drive (network share).
Next step would be a solution to synchronize your client-machines, but i assume this would be fiddling.

All under the assumption that it is at least possible to install games on the virtual windows-machine (running them probably won't work).

Comment: It would work, but not well.

Comment: A possibly better solution would be something like [Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) where to provide that synchronize solution. Or something like google drive or dropbox as a more simple solution. maybe?